# required to write an efficiet query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I need help in writing a query.

Below is my DB structure

```
id  name    key    value
1   book1   key1    abc
2   book2   key2    aaa
3   book3   key5    abc
4   book4   key3    abc
5   book5   key2    aaa
6   book6   key2    aab
7   book7   key1    abc
8   book8   key2    abc
9   book9   key1    abc
10  book10  key1    abc
```

And I need those books whose key has combination key1 with value abc and key2 with value aaa.

SO it should return

```
1   book1   key1    abc
2   book2   key2    aaa
5   book5   key2    aaa
7   book7   key1    abc
9   book9   key1    abc
10  book10  key1    abc
```

book having key2 and value aab wont return.

P.s This is just an example structure I have made to demonstrate my need. Actually I am working on wordpress post meta table.

Comment: You're example does not agree with your description.  Do you want books where both conditions are true or either condition?

Comment: I want book where both the conditions are true. I have used pivoted table to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that according to your design at some point in time you'll have several `key` + `value` pairs per book. This means that you might wish to select books where several specific keys has some particular values.

This can be achieved with the following SQL (for the given example):

```sql
SELECT t.id,t.name,k.key1,k.key2
  FROM test t
  JOIN (SELECT t.id,k1.value AS key1,k2.value AS key2
          FROM test t
          LEFT JOIN test k1 ON t.id=k1.id AND k1.`key`='key1'
          LEFT JOIN test k2 ON t.id=k2.id AND k2.`key`='key2'
  ) k ON t.id = k.id
WHERE k.key1='abc' OR k.key2 = 'aaa';
```

The inner part will create a pivoted table with keys in subject, while the outer part will perform the result filtering. You can play around with this setup [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/deb21/6).

Though, for such design, I would recommend splitting the table in subject into 2 separate ones: `books` and `params`. You can observe such setup [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b0ac/1).
Note, that if you'll change filter condition to be `k.key1='abc' AND k.key2 = 'aaa'`, then you'll have only `book10` matching.

This example is quite simple, but it gives the idea.

Comment: I cant actually split the tables as it is a a wordpress default. Thanks for the suggestion It worked

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, name, key, value from <yourTable> 
where key = "key1" 
or (key = "key2" and value = "aaa");
```

You may also want to take a look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/searching-on-two-keys.html).

Comment: Can you please see my comment below Matten answer. Is that possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    id, name, key, value from <table> 
where 
    (key = "key1" and value="abc")
or 
    (key = "key2" and value = "aaa");
```

Comment: Can I use AND in between them. Usecase would be that I have 1 book with 2 keys. And its key1 should have value abc and key2 should have value aaa. If any of the key fail the result will fail. Is that possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE key='key1' AND value='abc'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE key='key2' AND value='aaa'
```

Comment: Have u seen Matten solution. Which one you think is faster ?

Comment: Actual run times would need to be compared over large data sets verify. I wouldn't expect to see a significant difference, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is to check if the value has key1 and abc OR key2 and aaa, so it can either return the key1 and key2

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE key = 'key1' AND value ='abc' OR key = 'key2' AND value = 'aaa'
```